# Errors in running Leach Protocol in Omnet++(Castalia )

Tags: omnet++

I am running Leach protocol simulations in Castalia Omnet++ with the following simulation parameters:

```
sim-time-limit = 100s 
SN.field_x = 70
SN.field_y = 70                     
SN.numNodes = 10     
SN.deployment = "[1..9]->uniform"
SN.node[*].Communication.RoutingProtocolName = "LeachRouting"
SN.node[*].Communication.Routing.netBufferSize = 1000 
SN.node[0].Communication.Routing.isSink = true
SN.node[*].Communication.Routing.slotLength = 0.2
SN.node[*].Communication.Routing.roundLength = 20s
SN.node[*].Communication.Routing.percentage = 0.05
SN.node[*].Communication.Routing.powersConfig = xmldoc("powersConfig.xml") 
SN.node[*].ApplicationName = "ThroughputTest" 
SN.node[*].Application.packet_rate = 1
SN.node[*].Application.constantDataPayload = 200
```

After running simulations, I checked the Castalia trace file and found the following errors:

> SN.node[1].Communication.Radio Failed packet (WC_SIGNAL_START) from
>   node 6, radio not in RX state
>   SN.node[1].Communication.Radio Failed packet (WC_SIGNAL_END) from node
>   6, NO interference

Are these errors occurs due to simulation parameters or is there any other reason?

Answer (score 2):

The messages you see are not errors per se. It could be normal behaviour. The  messages just tell you that when a packet from node 6 arrived at node 1, node 1 did not have its radio in RX mode (listening) so it could not receive the packet.

This is a problem only when you lose most of your info-carrying packets, or you do not have a way to recover from such losses. You do not provide information whether this is the case or not.

The MAC plays a crucial role in this. The MAC puts the radio in RX or TX or Sleep mode. In the list of simulation parameters, the MAC is absent. If we assume that you use the default value, then this is bypassMAC that does not put the Radio to Sleep mode. Only way to have this message appear is for node 1 to TX at the same time it receives the packet from node 6.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I have set node 3 as a cluster head. majority of packets are getting lost. After running simulations, Castalia trace file shows the following error

SN.node[3].Communication.Radio           Failed packet (WC_SIGNAL_END) from node 1, NO interference

Comment: Have you understood my answer? You insist calling this message an error. Also you have not indicated what MAC protocol you are using.

Comment: I am using default settings i.e. bypassMAC.. Is there any other way to handle this issue as because In my simulations I set:

packet rate 1 packets/sec
num of nodes = 8
sim_time=100 sec

only 150 packets received while 500+ failed to deliver at CH. 
following is the log: 
SN.node[3].Communication.Radio Failed packet (WC_SIGNAL_END) from node 1, NO interference

Comment: Update your question with as much detail as possible. Here's a guide on how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

These are normal messages, not errors. You can check Radio.cc to know why these messages are generated and adjust your code.